# Issue with tuples in otherwise working program

Tags: python, tuples

I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Data\Box Sync\Box Sync\run9.py", line 122, in <module>
    print  "%11s %11s %10.f %17.f %1.2f %7.f %2.2f %2.2f %2.2f" %(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3], i[4], i[5], i[6], i[7], i[8])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I have tested all the lines previous and they are working fine. I get that the tuples are out of range when I have added i[6] and subsequent parts in the if I try to remove them then I get that there enough arguments for format string; which makes sense. What I cannot figure out is why the tuple out of range error is coming from. suggestions?

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if j > i:
            flydrivelist.append((P[i][0], P[j][0], D[i][j], E[i][j], R[i][j], D[i][j]-E[i][j], round(D[i][j] / drive, 2), round(E[i][j] / fly, 2), round((D[i][j] / drive) / (E[i][j] / fly), 2) ))
            #print flydrivelist this was used to test values; they are coming out correctly...
for i in sortedlist:
   print  "%11s %11s %10.f %17.f %21.2f %7.f %2.2f %2.2f %2.2f" %(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3], i[4], i[5], i[6], i[7], i[8])
```

Comment: what is the value of n?

Comment: How is sortedlist computed? What are its dimensions?

Comment: n is the number of rows of a list - in this case it is 12

Comment: The list is sorted previously using a sorted command. the sorted list does it in the order of the ratios. that part worked fine but the addition of list items 6, 7, and 8 is where the issue arose in the print.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer by wim i is out of range. Try displaying the length of i before your print statement i.e. len(i)

Answer (score 1):

This means your object `i` is a tuple and it has less than 9 elements.  It's an error message raised from `tuple.__getitem__`:

```
>>> ('a', 'b')[3]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

If you used the normal method of %-formatting, i.e. putting the tuple itself, you would see a different (and probably more useful) error message:

```
>>> '%s %s %s' % (0, 1)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```